# conjugacy action of a subgroup of a finite group on the lattice of subgroup in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, gap

Let $G$ be a  finite group with the lattice of subgroups ${\mathcal L}(G)$ and let $H$ 
be a subgroup of $G$, which acts on ${\mathcal L}(G)$  by conjugation. 
That is for each $h\in H$ and each $T\in {\mathcal L}(G)$, define $T.h:=h^{-1}Th$ . 
How could we determine this action in a GAP code and compute the orbits of this action?
(For example let $G:=S_4$, the symmetric group on four letters
and $H:= A_4$, the alternating  group  on four letters).

Any answer will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first get the subgroups of $G$ in a list, for example from the conjugacy classes of subgroups

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(4);;H:=AlternatingGroup(4);;
gap> subs:=Concatenation(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),AsList));;
```

The action by conjugation is by the `^` operator, so

```
gap> Orbits(H,subs);
[ [ Group(()) ],
  [ Group([ (3,4) ]), Group([ (1,4) ]), Group([ (2,4) ]), Group([ (1,2) ]),
  Group([ (2,3) ]), Group([ (1,3) ]) ], [...]
```

gives you the orbits. Similarly `Action` (or `ActionHomomorphism`) gives you the permutation action image.

Comment: Wouldn't $\mathtt{subs:=AllSubgroups(G);}$ have the same effect as your assignment?

Comment: @DerekHolt  Yes, it would. But knowing where the list comes from might help to reduce the problem if there are 100000s of subgroups.

Comment: Dear Professor Alexander Hulpke, thank you very much for your contribution and exact answer!